# cwd back to the original path

Tags: c, linux, shell, chdir

I am making my own shell using C-language.

In the initial stage my cwd is say "/Users/Henry/test".

One of the feature is that when i open a file the shell should not search for the file in the current working folder (cwd).

Instead it should search in folder "/usr" then "/usr/bin". My code:

```
int commandHandler(char** parsed)
{
        chdir("/usr");
        int ret;
        ret = chdir(parsed[1]);
        if(ret != 0)
           chdir("/usr/bin");
           ret = chdir(parsed[1]);
        return 0;
}
```

This changes my current working directory to "/usr/bin".

This functionality is only for "cd" command. Other commands like "ls", file execution ./out and so on should use the actual working directory "/Users/Henry/test".

How do i change my directory back? Can i set a global variable with the directory name at the initialisation of the program and then call it whenever i want to change the cwd back?

Comment: Yes, you could do that.

Comment: Do you try to get CWD with `getcwd(...)` function before `chdir` call ? Just recall `chdir` with saved vaue

Comment: Or store it in a buffer declared in the current function context. Globals should be avoided where possible, if stack is cheap.

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable mechanism uses POSIX function [`fchdir()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fchdir.html) in combination with [`open()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html).  You use `open()` to open the directory (the `O_DIRECTORY` flags is not available everywhere, but can usually be omitted if not defined) and save the file descriptor.  You then use `chdir()` to change to the named directory, but you can use `fchdir()` to change back to the original directory, passing the saved file descriptor.

```
int owd = open(".", O_RDONLY|O_DIRECTORY);
…error check…
if (chdir(new_working_directory) == 0)
{
    …work in new directory…
    fchdir(owd);    // Change back to old working directory
}
close(owd);         // Avoid leaking file descriptors
```

Comment: You might add that this method allows changing back to the original directory even if it was renamed or moved, ie: if the path was changed and even if it was removed.